# c# registry settings RegistryValueKind REG_MULTI_SZ

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

Hi I have a below code to set registry value

```
string encyrptedParam       = Class.Encrypt("TEst1");
string encryptedUserWarning = Class.Encrypt("Test2;TEst3");

using (var rk = RegistryHelpers.GetRegistryKey())
{
    rk.SetValue("Parameters", encyrptedParam,RegistryValueKind.String);
    rk.SetValue("UserWarnings", encryptedUserWarning, RegistryValueKind.MultiString);
}
```

While setting 'UserWarnings' I get the below error: 
The type of the value object did not match the specified RegistryValueKind or the object could not be properly converted

Let us know what I am doing wrong here

Thanks

Comment: MultiString is like string1\0string2\0\0 - are you sure its the correct format. User warnings must be like a null separated string of user warning strings again terminated by \0. Your Class.Encrypt essentially makes it string so better use RegistryValueKind.String for UserWarnings as well and after you decrypt split by ;

Comment: It is not generally possible to store encrypted data in a string.  Unless the encryption method uses Convert.ToBase64String().  The sane way to go about it is to avoid stringly typing, have the encryption method return byte[] and use RegistryValueKind.Binary

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs this, basically you want to send in a string array.

```
rk.SetValue("UserWarnings", new [] {encryptedUserWarning}, RegistryValueKind.MultiString);
```